# How to use a type from an optional dependency in a declaration file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependencies, declaration, option-type

I have a JS library that does something like so:

```
let OptionalLib;
function foo() {
  OptionalLib = require('optionallib');
  // Do stuff...
  return (something from optional lib);
}
```

then I add typings in a .d.ts file:

```
declare module 'mylib' {
  import { Bar } from 'optionallib';
  export function foo(): Bar;
}
```

the problem with this is that if the optional library is not installed, TS will complain about not being able to import it, even though it's optional. I tried doing this in order to have the typings for the library when it's not installed:

```
declare module 'optionallib' {
  interface Bar {}
}
```

but the problem with this is that it seems to replace the actual module completely when it is installed (no declaration merging?), so if it exported `Baz`, it won't be found.

So how should I handle this problem? I am aware that I can split the part relying on this optional library to another library, but I feel it would be more convenient to leave it in since its so small.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am currently wondering about this same problem

Comment: I have not, I have just typed it as `any` for now.

Comment: I cant believe this does not exist. Seriously.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle optional peer dependencies when publishing a TypeScript package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392809/how-do-i-handle-optional-peer-dependencies-when-publishing-a-typescript-package)

Comment: I'm not working on this problem anymore, but creating an interface that fits both seems like a good idea.